# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in scheme at index 0:

Tags: android

I have some error like this if running at ics (for 2.3 running well):

```
03-01 10:15:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(844): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
03-01 10:15:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(844): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-01 10:15:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
03-01 10:15:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
03-01 10:15:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
03-01 10:15:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
03-01 10:15:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-01 10:15:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
03-01 10:15:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
03-01 10:15:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-01 10:15:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(844): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in scheme at index 0:   http://localhost/android/data_janji.php?id_nasabah=40
03-01 10:15:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:727)
03-01 10:15:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.<init>(HttpGet.java:75)
03-01 10:15:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at com.mpegadaian.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:109)
03-01 10:15:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at com.mpegadaian.DaftarJanjiActivity$LoadGadai.doInBackground(DaftarJanjiActivity.java:132)
03-01 10:15:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at com.mpegadaian.DaftarJanjiActivity$LoadGadai.doInBackground(DaftarJanjiActivity.java:1)
```

I checked `data_janji.php` to see if I access cross form browser, the result is fine:

```
{"data_janji":[{"nama_brg":"ANTING ANTING 10GR","id_janji":"9","id_gadai":"23","tgl_janji":"01-March-2013","pesan":"tebus bsk"}]}
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

It seems you have some blanks (empty spaces) in front of the `http:`, remove them.

Comment: I had quotes around mine :)

Comment: single quote from copy/pasting from another source here. Thanks

Comment: I did... I can't believe it, but an extra space snuck in there.